# Convert SQL Server database to PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, database-migration

I'm looking for a free software to convert an SQL Server database to PostgreSQL database, do you know where could I find it?

Comment: https://github.com/dalibo/sqlserver2pgsql

Comment: I'm looking for an easier tool. I tried with FullConvert(trial version) but it replaced a lot of rows with ** TRIAL**

Comment: By "easier" I assume you mean "freer"?

Comment: With FullConvert I just entered my two databases informations and it automatically created all tables from Sql Serve to my PostGre database, with datas. No configuration, no commandlines, that's what I meaned by "easier"

Comment: [it's either Postgres or PostgreSQL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines), but **not** "PostGre"

Comment: See also: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server_to_PostgreSQL_Migration_by_Ian_Harding and https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#Microsoft_SQL_Server

Comment: https://dbconvert.com/mssql/postgresql/ and https://www.enterprisedb.com/products/edb-postgres-platform/edb-migration-toolkit

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name These products aren't free ! It's ok I used again FullConverter in Trial mode then, I generated scripts of my Sql Server datas and I executed them in PostGreSql